# How to find (and rename) files with invalid characters (Latin1) on UTF-8 system?

Tags: bash, filenames, unicode

I've got some old files from a Latin1 based system with names that are invalid on my UTF-8 system. They show as various codes or question marks. For example:

```
/tmp/test $ ls -1
'FRg_Pause lecture_'$'\371''.png'
'FRg_Pause lecture_'$'\353''.png'
'FRg_Pause lecture_'$'\350''.png'
'FRg_Pause lecture_'$'\374''.png'

/tmp/test $ find .
./FRg_Pause lecture_?.png
./FRg_Pause lecture_?.png
./FRg_Pause lecture_?.png
./FRg_Pause lecture_?.png

/tmp/test $ tar cvfz test.tar.gz *.png
FRg_Pause lecture_\351.png
FRg_Pause lecture_\352.png
FRg_Pause lecture_\340.png
FRg_Pause lecture_\374.png
```

I would like to rename them, ideally to the correct UTF-8 name. For example:

```
FRg_Pause lecture_\340.png -> FRg_Pause lecture_à.png
```

But even renaming them to, I don't know, "FRg_Pause lecture_340.png" would be ok. As long as the new names are valid UTF-8 and our tools stop complaining.

However one complication is that there are many files that have correct UTF-8 names so I can't just switch the OS to Latin1 and be done with it. I need to find the files that are not UTF-8 (and there are many, in many directories) and do something about them.

Any ideas? For start I find it hard to even find the files.

Comment: I have used *detox* ( https://linux.die.net/man/1/detox ) for some similar purpose in the past. Perhaps could it help you as well.

Comment: `man convmv` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Artem and MC68020 for the suggestions in the comments.

Unfortunately `detox` didn't work because it wanted to create duplicates (e.g. `\340` and `\342` were both mapped to `a`).

On the other hand `convmv` has done the job correctly.

```
/tmp/test $ convmv -f latin1 -t utf-8 -r . --notest
mv "./FRg_Pause lecture_�.png"  "./FRg_Pause lecture_ù.png"
mv "./FRg_Pause lecture_�.png"  "./FRg_Pause lecture_ë.png"
mv "./FRg_Pause lecture_�.png"  "./FRg_Pause lecture_è.png"
mv "./FRg_Pause lecture_�.png"  "./FRg_Pause lecture_ü.png"
mv "./FRg_Pause lecture_�.png"  "./FRg_Pause lecture_à.png"
mv "./FRg_Pause lecture_�.png"  "./FRg_Pause lecture_ê.png"
mv "./FRg_Pause lecture_�.png"  "./FRg_Pause lecture_é.png"
Ready! I converted 7 files in 0 seconds.
```

Now on to fixing the thousands of files on the NAS :)